# Aliasing a function with default parameters in bash

Tags: bash, parameters

I would like to create an alias for an existing function to pass some parameters. Furthermore the alias should be able to take any flags of the original function and parse them correctly. In my specific case I am using [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher).

When using `zsh` I can just add in my `.zshrc` file

```
alias -g ag="ag --nogroup --smart-case"
```

How can I obtain the same effect with bash only environments? The code

```
myfunc() {
    ag --nogroup --smart-case "$*"
}

alias ag=myfunc
```

works for the base case (i.e. `ag hello`) but does not accept parameters as in `ag hello --context 2`

Comment: What about this didn't work? The use of `ag` as the alias?

Comment: I just want to turn on some options by default

Comment: Yes... and? What about what you listed in the post didn't work to do that?

Comment: It didn't work in the case of adding extra flags as in `ag hello --context 2`

Comment: Didn't work **how**? Did you get an error? Were the arguments just ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the correct parameter substitution is important.

```
ag() {
  command ag --nogroup --smart-case "$@"
}
```

Comment: @EtanReisner: Turns out it was the wrong solution there.

Comment: Huh, I thought `command` wouldn't find shell functions but `command -V` does. That's interesting (and annoying).

Comment: I thought they should be passed as a single argument, but apparently they need to be separated

Answer (score 0):

Since this case is simple enough (all the extra parameters go at the end) an alias will be sufficient:

```
alias ag="ag --nogroup --smart-case"
```

The `-g` option is not valid for bash `alias`.